# What's the difference between generators and closures in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, closures, generator

What's the difference between doing these two solutions to the same problem?

## Closure Method

```js
const numberIncrementer = startValue => () => startValue++
const getNextNumber = numberIncrementer(0)

console.log(getNextNumber())
// 0

console.log(getNextNumber())
// 1

console.log(getNextNumber())
// 2
```

## Generator Method

```js
const numberIncrementer = function*(startValue) {
    while(true) {
        yield startValue++
    }
}

const numberFactory = numberIncrementer(0)
const getNextNumber = () => numberFactory.next().value

console.log(getNextNumber())
// 0

console.log(getNextNumber())
// 1

console.log(getNextNumber())
// 2
```

Viewing these two methods, what reason do I have to choose one over the other?

Comment: Well the syntax is completely different? And try to do anything a bit more complex than an infinite loop…

Comment: There is tons of overlap in many APIs. In this example, the differences aren't really shown -- especially since it appears a closure is being created by the generator. The main differences come up in terms of async flow. While you have the `.next()` method hard coded into your `getNextNumber` function, it would perhaps more appropriately be outside of that function so you can call `next()` after some `async` work returns with data. But i could be wrong about all of this...

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/45093404/1048572 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/23613612/1048572

Comment: Functionally speaking, one big difference is that Generators produce [`Iterators`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Iterator), so you can use `for..of` to iterate over the data a generator produces. Another difference as that with the Generator you could process an infinite sequence.

Comment: There cannot be any difference in this case because the final result is a function that returns ever-increaing number. The same applies to `var foo = 1` vs `var foo = incrediblyComplexFunctionThatReturns1()` or any other comparison where KISS principle is applicable.

Comment: Closures are sort of higher order functions and hence very powerful. It wouldn't surprise me, if they are equally expressive as generators in many scenarios. A closure provides state between function calls, which is stored on the heap and can consume (arguments) and produce (return) values. Sounds a lot like generators, at least technically. It's probably awkward in complex scenarios to maintain state like generators do, though.

Comment: To me it seems like comparing apples with oranges. Generators are basically syntactic sugar for creating iterators. Closures are functions that have free variables. Generator functions can be closures.

Comment: What do you think happens when you do `const numberFactory = numberIncrementer(0)` ..? The `numberFactory` function is being assigned with an iterator function which has access to the value within the generator function. It uses closures. So Generators work on the basis of closures but they are invented to introduce the abstraction of laziness to JS.

Comment: @Redu Lazyness doesn't abstract anything. It is an evaluation strategy. Since functions/lambdas are nothing more then named/anonymous, lazy evaluated expressions, all you need in Javascript to express lazy evaluation are functions.

Comment: @Bergi So generators are essentially syntactic sugar for stateful closures? I mean they seem to be really helpful as coroutine engines, but are they mandatory?

Comment: @ftor Yes, exactly that. You can instantiate stateful iterator objects with `next` methods in any way you like, but generators provide very powerful syntactic sugar for that. What do you mean by "mandatory"?

Answer (score 13):

In the following contrived example I convert an `Object` into a `Map` without relying on an intermediate `Array`:

```js
function* entries(o) {
  for (let k in o) yield [k, o[k]];
}

const m = new Map(entries({foo: 1, bar: 2}))

console.log(
  Array.from(m) // [["foo", 1], ["bar", 2]]
);
```

This doesn't work with a closure, as you cannot access the state of the `for/in` loop to maintain it across function calls. The state is encapsulated within the loop construct. So there are cases that can be expressed with generators but not with closures.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to [a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46607481/17030712): while there might be **cases that can be expressed with generators but not with closures** (I was looking for that answer as well), the one demonstrated by **user6445533** is not one of them. Here is it, done with closures:

```js
const entries = (o) => ({
  entries: Object.entries(o),
  next() {
    return this.entries.length
      ? { value: this.entries.shift() }
      : { done: true };  
  },
  [Symbol.iterator]() {
    return this;
  }
});

const m = new Map(entries({foo: 1, bar: 2}));

console.log(Array.from(m)); // [["foo", 1], ["bar", 2]]
```

So, maybe it's all syntactic sugar in the end?

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, isn't using `Symbol.iterator` the same as creating a generator?

Comment: @KevinGhadyani By using `Symbol.iterator` your object is conforming to the [iterable protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_generators#iterables), which generators must follow too. My point would be, a generator is just a closure conforming to a protocol, and the keywords `function *` and `yield` are only innovations in terms of syntax