# What is the best practice to create an async iterator? Should I use an async generator function or rather use Symbol.asyncIterator?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, iterator, generator

This code works as expected:

```js
function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function getAsyncData() {
    await sleep(1000);  // simulate database/network delay...
    return [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];  // ...then return some data
}

const asyncIterable = (async function* filterAsyncData() {
    const items = await getAsyncData();

    for (const item of items) {
        yield item;
    }
})();

const asyncIterable2 = {
    [Symbol.asyncIterator]() {
        return {
            values: null,
            idx: 0,
            async next() {
                if (this.values === null) {
                    this.values = await getAsyncData();
                }

                if (this.idx < this.values.length) {
                    this.idx = this.idx + 1;
                    return Promise.resolve({ value: this.values[this.idx - 1], done: false });
                }

                return Promise.resolve({ done: true });
            }
        };
    }
};

async function main() {
    for await (const filteredItem of asyncIterable) {
        console.log(filteredItem);
    }
}

main()
```

It does not mather if I use `asyncIterable` or `asyncIterable2` in the `main` function, I always get the same result. What is the best practice to define my iterable? Are there any guidelines about which option is preferred? Why?

Comment: In this particular case, you actually should be doing `for (const filteredItem of await getAsyncData()) {` instead of using async iterators/iterables at all.

Comment: You are completely right! But I do need the iterator because I am mocking the return value of an async generator function in a test :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the [same as for synchronous iterators](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45093404/1048572): generator functions are much easier to write, and easier to get correct, than implementing the iterator object manually. Do this only if you need some non-standard behaviour that cannot be achieved otherwise. With asynchronous generator functions specifically, you even get the proper queueing of `next` calls for free, which is a real headache to get right (your `asyncIterable2` fails this<sup>1</sup>).

The most common implementation of iterables is to make the `Symbol.asyncIterator` method an async generator method:

```
const asyncIterable = {
    async *[Symbol.asyncIterator]() {
         yield* await getAsyncData();
    },
};
```

<sub>1: `const it = asyncIterable2[Symbol.asyncIterator](); it.next(); it.next()` - without any `await`s in between - will call `getAsyncData` twice, because `this.values == null` in both calls</sub>

Comment: What is queuing of `next` calls? And why am I doing it wrong in `asyncIterable2`?

EDIT: Now I have seen the edit. Thank you for the amazing answer! I wish I could give you more than one upvote :D