# Should one use for-of or forEach when iterating through an array?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Also, is this a style question or a functional question?  Is it a matter of preference or is one better?  I'm trying to understand the purpose of for-of.

Usually I use,

```js
let iterable = [10, 20, 30];

iterable.forEach((val) => {
   console.log(val);
})
```

But I see that this new syntax is available.

```js
let iterable = [10, 20, 30];
    
for (let value of iterable) {
   console.log(value);
}
```

Can one provide an example of a best use case for for-of that might illuminate when one should use it?

Comment: I would not say this is entirely opinion based, since there are definitely some differences between `forEach` and `for/of`. For example, `for/of` can be used to iterate over a generator, where `forEach` cannot. So it is not merely a matter of preference.

Comment: Some iterables don't have a `forEach()` like a [`FileList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList) for example. Other than iterables that don't implement `forEach()`, it's purely a matter of preference.

Comment: If you don't want to mutate ```value```, you could and should write ```const value of iterable```

Comment: I think nowadays the question is why one would ever prefer `forEach` over `for..of`. The only practical advantage worth noting (that I can think of) is support for older browsers without transpilation.

Answer (score 182):

I recommend to always use `for … of` in ES6.

- It works on any [iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41559281/1048572)
- It supports all kinds of control flow in the loop body, like `continue`, `break`, `return`, `yield` and `await`.

Also I personally find it more readable, but that comes down to preference. Some people think `forEach` is a more functional style, but that's wrong - it has no result value and is all about doing side effects, so an imperative-looking loop fits that purpose better.

Performance is not a concern, [in modern engines all loop styles are equivalent](https://youtu.be/m9cTaYI95Zc?t=951).

Comment: `await` can actually be used within a forEach loop and I'd argue it is actually easier. With `for-of` you have to wrap the whole thing in an async function. With `forEach` you can just make the callback async: `[1,2,3].forEach(async (value) => {await new Promise(resolve=>console.log(value))})`

Comment: @Forivin [That doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37576685/1048572), the loop will not be waited for. Your code is equivalent to just creating the promise and not using `async`/`await` at all.

Comment: Well, it does work, the use-case is just different and admittedly unusual. But the promise executors will be in fact be called.

Comment: Well for the different use case you don't need `await` at all, and so you could just write `for (const value of [1,2,3]) { new Promise(resolve => console.log(value)); }`

Comment: @Forivin You can do it using Array methods with `Promise.all` as long as you return an Array - so just use `map` instead of `forEach` as in: `await Promise.all([1, 2, 3].map(async value => { const result = await foo(value); }))` this would await each async handler without having to use `for..of`.

Comment: @Forivin no it doesn't work, yes it will be called, but the point is it won't be awaited, there are Promise.all/allSettled api for that

Comment: This comment is exactly why forEach should never be used, it's deceiving. It seems that the code inside the loop is executed synchronously but it's not, it's concurrent. I've seen it on the wild and produced the most bizarre bugs. Junior devs are ususally bitten by this.

Comment: The fact that `forEach` does not support control flow changes IMHO is the key advantage. If I read `forEach` I expect an independent iteration over all elements. With `for..of` this guarantee goes away and more mental resources are required. Only express the flexibility you actually need.

Answer (score 70):

This is a very interesting question which has been discussed in many other sites. I'll post the basics of what I have read.

> **ForEach** exclusively belong to the royal family of Arrays. The forEach method was introduced with lineage to the prototypal inheritance of Array object! Needless to say, the forEach clause works only with those data structure which are Arrays. The method basically iterates over the elements of the array and executes a callback function [basically some executable function/ fun activity].

---

> **The for-of loop** is adequately new to the JS world and packs in super-powers! Voilaaaaaaa! The for-of loop creates a loop iterating over iterable member objects. The list is an extensive one such as

- Array
- Map
- Set
- String
- TypedArray
- Other W3C classes

> You need to know that this bad-ass boy emerged with the birth of ES6 in 2015. So, it offers plenty of flexibility in usage

---

**Performance**

In performance, `for...of` is faster than `forEach`. [Results can be found here](https://jsperf.com/for-of-vs-for-each2)

`forEach` is 24% slower than `for...of`

---

### Update

There are several other iterable classes in the W3C specification, like FileList, as I mentioned above. And in recent drafts of W3C (around when ES6 was released), collections like HTMLCollection and NodeList now implement forEach() as well, not just Array anymore. *By [@Patrick Roberts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1541563/patrick-roberts)*

---

Source Links:

- https://codeburst.io/foreach-vs-for-of-vs-for-in-tug-of-for-d8f935396648
- https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/4spd5b/forof_vs_foreach/

Comment: That list only mentions classes in the ECMAScript specification. There are several other iterable classes in the W3C specification, like `FileList`, as I mentioned above. And in recent drafts of W3C (around when ES6 was released), collections like `HTMLCollection` and `NodeList` now implement `forEach()` as well, not just `Array` anymore.

Comment: In latest firefox, `forEach` is faster than `for of`, but in chrome, `for of` is faster.

Comment: Intersting. It seems that depends on the browser javascript engine. Mozilla uses SpiderMonkey while Chrome uses Chrome v8. Maybe the implementation of `forEach` and `for...of` is different.

Comment: Unless there's a fundamental reason why some constructs are much harder to optimize for, these kinds of benchmark comparisons are <extremely> brittle. For example, on the most recent v8 version 10.4.123.20 I'm finding that `for...of`, `for`, and `forEach` basically have the same performance.

Comment: You had me at "super-powers!" "Voilaaaaaaa" and "bad-ass."

Comment: "In performance, for...of is faster than forEach" **Never** make such general statements.  Performace depends on so many factors and mostly is irrelevant when your code doesn't do what it is suposed to do or when it's impossible to maintain because of over-optimzation.