# Return from function with promise

Tags: javascript

I'll be as brief as possible. Here is simple example

```
function find5 (arr)
{
    return new Promise (function (resolve, reject)
    {
        arr.forEach (
            function (el)
            {
                console.log (el);
                if (el == 5)
                {
                    return resolve (true);
                }
            }
        );
        return reject (false);
    });
}
async function init ()
{
    try {
        var res = await find5 ([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]);
        console.log (res);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log (e);
    }
}
init ();
```

Here is output: `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 true`
I want to exit from function `find5` but return `resolve (true);`. I think it returns from function `(el)`. How do I jump here: `return new Promise`?

Need help with code.

Comment: Note that JS has a whole bunch of cool array functions that you might not know about, like `if (arr.some(e => e===5)) resolve(true)`, which will look for an element that matches and immediately stops looking if it finds one.

Comment: Returning from the `forEach()` callback function doesn't end the `forEach()` loop. `resolve()` doesn't stop the loop, either.

Comment: You can use an ordinary `for` loop, then you can break out of the loop after calling `resolve()`.

Comment: I know that loop doesnt stop. Show me how to exit function ))

Comment: I want foreach ))

Comment: @AlexGoodie, you may *want* `forEach`, but you *need* `for`. The only way to "break" out of a `forEach` loop is to throw an error. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641347/short-circuit-array-foreach-like-calling-break for how that would work.

Comment: The promise is unrelated to your actual problem, which is about returning early from the `forEach` loop. But why are you using a promise at all? Nothing in your code is asynchronous! `find5` should just return the boolean value, not a fulfilled promise for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this a lot using `async` syntax instead of returning an explicit Promise, and by using one of the many super useful `Array` functions that JS has built in (you *definitely* want to give the list over on [the Array docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) a read-through, there are way more than you think):

```js
async function find5(arr) {
  if (!arr) {
    throw new Error(`no input array passed to find5!`);
  }
  if (!Array.isArray(arr)) {
    throw new Error(`input to find5 was not an array!`);
  }
  // this will either be true, or false.
  return arr.some((e) => (e === 5));
}

async function init(arr) {
  try {
    const res = await find5(arr);
    console.log(res);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e.message);
  }
}

init();
init("lol");
init([1,2,4,8,16]);
init([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]);
```

And note that the `find5` function shouldn't be throwing an error just because you can't find the element (or in Promise terms, should not be rejecting): that's an "emergency" mechanism for when unexpected things happen. For instance, if `arr` is undefined or it's not an array, *that's* grounds to throw an error, but the array not containing an element `5` is not. The code still works, and finishes, it just didn't see the element so it reports `false`.

If course, if this is *really* the only thing we're doing, then that's still overkill, we don't need *any* of that. Just use [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) directly:

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
const res = arr.some((e) => (e === 5));
console.log(res);
```

Done.

Comment: Guys, I am a coder with a 20-years expirience (not JS). I know how to write for loops. Show me how to exit from main function )))

Comment: Cool: as a staff enginer I'm going to assume that  means you're at least a senior yourself, and so I'm going to assume you care a lot about knowing what built-ins are available to streamline what you're doing. The solution here is to not try to "shortcut the forEach": that's literally what `.some` exists for =)

Comment: my brain blow up from shorts like this )))

Comment: If this blows up your brain, then it's time to get comfortable with modern JS. It's pretty much nothing like what JS looked like 20, or even 10 years ago (and there are a LOT of bad tutorials out there these days because they still teach legacy or even deprecated JS syntax and methodology. Like using `var`: don't do that, use `let` or `const` in modern JS depending on whether you need a mutable or immutable variable)

Comment: It's actually a quest question. How to solve it by one line code?
It's like a brainwave before bedtime ))

Comment: Not really, any junior dev with modern JS knowledge can probably understand this code, but it _does_ require knowing modern JS =)

Comment: "*You can simplify this a lot*" - I agree, but instead of using an `async` function you could simplify this further by just using a normal `function`?

Comment: We can, but I'd like to imagine that whatever the real code is might not be quite as simple as what we're being shown. If it is, of course, then yeah there is zero reason for `find5` to be async at all. Or, really, even a function at all; just inline the `arr.some()` check, there's nothing to wait for.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return inside a `forEach` in javaScript .. So your loop just continues to run.  You can read more about that Here [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#return_value) -- You'll find in the docs:

> **Return value**
> None (undefined).

To properly do it, your going to need a `for loop` instead.

```js
function find5(arr) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      console.log(arr[i]);
      if (arr[i] === 5) {
        console.log('made');
        return resolve(true);
      }
    }

    return reject(false);
  });
}
async function init() {
  try {
    var res = await find5([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]);
    console.log(res);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
init();
```

Comment: I want foreach not for loops ))

Comment: @AlexGoodie -- Did you read my answer thoroughly?  It's **impossible** to return from a forEach as it's not supported  .. [Read the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#return_value)!  It doesn't matter that you **want** a forEach .. It's not possible here.  As a "Senior Dev" you should be open to all programming possibilities, and not so closed off to other solutions that **work**.

Comment: why would you want to use foreach for a use case that wants to break the loop? thats just silly tho. If you must complete the iteration (which you absolutely should not) bind the return value to a variable and return after the foreach block

Comment: @AlexGoodie If you don't like `for (let i=0; i<arr.length; i++)` loops, use a `for (const el of arr)` loop. [Much better than the `.forEach()` method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50844413/1048572): it works with standard control flow instructions like `break` or `return`!

Answer (score -3):

```
//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77240304/return-from-function-with-promise

function find5 (arr)
{
    return new Promise (function (resolve, reject)
    {
        var finded = false;
        arr.forEach (
            function (el)
            {
                if (finded == false)
                {
                    console.log (el);
                    if (el == 5)
                    {
                        finded = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        );
        if (finded == true)
        {
            return resolve (true);
        }
        return reject (false);
    });
}
async function init ()
{
    try {
        var res = await find5 ([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]);
        console.log (res);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log (e);
    }
}
init ();
```

It's bad code, I know, but as an option.

Comment: How close is this code to your actual use case? If your only goal is to determine whether or not an array contains a specific item, you can use `var result = array.includes(5)` and delete your `find5` function. If you need to do more logic, `array.some` might be more appropriate. Either way, you're not getting anything by making the `find5` function asynchronous. Both `forEach` and `some` are synchronous in JavaScript.