# Verify Iterator versus AsyncIterator type

Tags: javascript, typescript, iterator

Is there any known trick in JavaScript to tell the difference between `Iterator` and `AsyncIterator`, without triggering iteration?

I'm trying to implement the following type checker:

```
function isAsyncIterator<T>(i: Iterator<T> | AsyncIterator<T>): boolean {
    // returns:
    //  - true, if i is an asycnronous iterator
    //  - false, if i is a syncronous iterator
}
```

I know that calling `next` would tell us so, but I need it at the point when I cannot trigger iteration.

Also, even though I gave the example in TypeScript, I need to check it strictly at run-time.

Comment: [According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#the_iterable_protocol), I don't think this is possible (beyond naive checks for `typeof obj.next === 'function'`, it says: "It is not possible to know reflectively whether a particular object implements the iterator protocol."

Comment: @Dai That's my feeling also, that's why I specifically phrased it as `any known trick`, as opposed to `any proper solution` :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think there is a *current* way to distinguish these. Especially since *anything* could be an iterator, as long as it fulfils the iterator protocol (has a `.next()` method that returns data in the correct form). Whether or not `next()` produces promises or not is unknown and probably unknowable. Consider `{ next() { return {value: 4, done: false }; } }` and `next() { return Promise.resolve({value: 4, done: false }); } }` no real way to determine which is synchronous or not. But I'd be really curious if it is indeed possible.

Comment: @VLAZ You could add a type-guard to every call to `next()` - though I'm not sure how it benefits anyone, really.

Comment: What do you need this for? How did you get an iterator in the first place without knowing whether you called `[Symbol.iterator]()` or `[Symbol.asyncIterator]()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible. *Iterators* are defined by a protocol, not by a tangible property, so due to the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) one cannot determine whether an object is an iterator without actually iterating it. See also the similar question [What is the technical definition of a Javascript iterable and how do you test for it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41559125/1048572).

However, there are good heuristics that will detect most well-behaved iterator implementations and all builtin iterators:

- Iterators typically are iterable (they couldn't be used in `for … of` loops otherwise, limiting their usefulness) and will delegate to themselves for that. So

  ```
  function isIterator(obj) {
      if (Object(obj) !== obj) return false;
      const method = obj[Symbol.iterator];
      if (typeof method != 'function') return false;
      const iter = method.call(obj);
      return iter === obj;
  }
  function isAsyncIterator(obj) {
      if (Object(obj) !== obj) return false;
      const method = obj[Symbol.asyncIterator];
      if (typeof method != 'function') return false;
      const aIter = method.call(obj);
      return aIter === obj;
  }
  ```
- Iterators inherit from the builtin `%IteratorPrototype%`. Until the [*iterator helpers* proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-iterator-helpers) will introduce the global `Iterator` constructor these objects are a bit cumbersome to access and test for, but it's possible nonetheless.

  ```
  const GeneratorPrototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(function*() {}).prototype;
  const IteratorPrototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(GeneratorPrototype);
  const AsyncGeneratorPrototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(async function*() {}).prototype;
  const AsyncIteratorPrototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(AsyncGeneratorPrototype);

  function isIterator(obj) {
      return IteratorPrototype.isPrototypeOf(obj);
  }
  function isAsyncIterator(obj) {
      return AsyncIteratorPrototype.isPrototypeOf(obj);
  }
  ```

  (Of course, like any `instanceof` check, this doesn't work with objects from other realms, which is why I would recommend the first approach)

Comment: Although I generally agree that it is impossible, without iteration, there is some confusion in the code, trying to detect an `Iterable`, as opposed to `Iterator`. Iterables do not require much of detection, their protocol makes it obvious. I'm strictly after `Iterator` detection in my question ;)

Comment: @vitaly-t The code is not trying to detect any `Iterable`, it tries to detect `IterableIterator`s where `iter === obj`

Comment: Line `const method = obj[Symbol.iterator];` is for an `Iterable` check, it doesn't belong to `isIterator` logic, because iterators never have that symbol.

Comment: @vitaly-t "*never have that symbol*"? They do. Sure, not all iterators do, but as I wrote, well-behaved iterators (that is most of them, and certainly all builtin ones) are `IterableIterator`s, which do inherit `[Symbol.iterator]() { return this; }` from `%IteratorPrototype%`. Testing for this behaviour allows cross-realm `isIterator` checks that don't rely on a specific prototype identity.

Comment: At the very least, I accept `It is not possible` part :)